# Add Friend through Facebook Dialog - Android Facebook SDK

Tags: android, addition, friend, facebook-android-sdk, fbdialogs

I am currently developing an Android app using the Facebook API. One module of my application consists in adding a friend (knowing the ID) and I would like to add a friend through the FB Dialog object.
I used the Facebook object with dialog method:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/dialog/ .
as well as the FbDialog class to try adding a friend through a dialog:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/ .
However, as it is written in the documentation only feed and oauth are supported through this dialog. As a consequence, when I use this dialog trying to add a friend, either it redirects me to my browser and the AddFriend web dialog, or it successfully open a dialog but with a message saying that this is not supported.

My question is: is it possible to have this dialog working with the Add friend mechanism in spite of what the documentation says? Maybe one of you guys has found a trick to do so. Or maybe it is just not possible, and I have to stay with this method (that is opening the web browser), which I find not very user-friendly for my app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you mean once i authorized using facebook then load my freinds ID...?

Comment: Yes, let's say that the application is already authorized by the user on Facebook. Then, the user is able to add a friend according to the id (id which has been retrieved before). The only thing that I would like is this Facebook dialog for adding the friend, without having to open the web browser.

Comment: Look this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11175665/710162 . Maybe it helps you