# Does Facebook API allow sending and accepting friend requests?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, friend

I have tried to comb through the Facebook Developers documentation http://developers.facebook.com/ but haven't been able to answer this question.

I would like to be able to send Facebook friend requests and accept friend requests in a webapp. Does Facebook API allow/enable such a function?

Comment: check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11175665/2310673)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this ? Its the recommended option since the api doesnt allow you to add randomly people with a call.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/

Edit: Here you have the reference for dialogs in android sdk 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/dialog/

Comment: Thank you! Will check it out. On first look, it does seem useful.