# Does Facebook Android SDK allow sending friend requests?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have started working with android a day ago, the same is true for the Facebook SDK and right now it's been 2 hours I have tried to find an answer for the above question. My findings say that it was possible but was removed in some later version.
source: [Does Facebook API allow sending and accepting friend requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663289/does-facebook-api-allow-sending-and-accepting-friend-requests)
I will like to know as of now, if it is possible or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your findings are correct. It is not possible anymore