# Sending A Friend Request In Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I already read a post here [How to send friend request using Facebook dialogs on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175483/how-to-send-friend-request-using-facebook-dialogs-on-android)

However, I'm not sure how to implement the advice. It seems like the accepted answer is now unavailable from facebook. And the second answer, which seems to be how people do it now, I'm not sure what params to use and I can't find it anywhere in the facebook docs.

Here is some info on how to send requests from facebook.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you download the sample app ([FriendSmash](https://github.com/fbsamples/android-friend-smash-v2)) to see how they implement Facebook api on Android application